# From where to serve multi-Resource Web UI pages in a RESTful architecture?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, url-rewriting

Almost all web content can be a resource to be served up on its own.  Web front-ends, however, mix unconnected resource content in order to serve the user with some desired experience.  A blog page might be laid out with its articles stacked on the left and a list of the site's other popular blogs on the right, as an example.  Let's say the web service for both of those resource lists are at uris: /blogs/{blogname}/entries and /popularblogs, respectively.

I'm using Spring's REST implementation and can infer return content-types.  So, when a request for html comes in, I could return a nice little facade to present the underlying atom lists for each of those examples.  *However, I still need to serve the web ui page that displays the left-right composite presentation from some where*.

**From what URI does the web user access that page?**

I figure there are 2 options:

1. I could have a 3rd uri for web ui pages, maybe splitting the uri tree into 2 roots, like /rest/** for restful web services (which would house web services for both lists in the example) and /web/** for web ui service (which would know to serve up the composite page at some uri and ajax call over to the /rest/** world for content as needed).
2. Or, I could return the composite web ui page from each of the blog-entries and popular-blogs rest requests when return content-type of html is inferred.

**What is the best practice?**

Any feedback is very, very much appreciated.  Thank you!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have decided with option #1.  Splitting rest URIs from the webapp.